# how to correctly rephrase the sentence

Tags: meaning, verbs, adjectives, adverbs

in the following sentence:

> ..such poor educational system produces scientifically sterile generations able just to regurgitate

what i ment be "scientifically sterile generations" is, a generation which has nothing to contribute to the science.

is the sentence correct? if no, please let me know how to rephrase it right with maintaing the same meaning

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Proofreading requests are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: "....such a poor educational system produces students who are capable only of regurgitating facts; they are incapable of creating new science."   The original sentence said that the generation was not capable of procreating, only of regurgitating.

Comment: Scientifically sterile? Is this figuratively sterile, statistically sterile, virtually sterile, metaphorically sterile, or actually sterile? Before rephrasing the sentence, I have to understand it. What does scientifically mean?

Comment: @Stan it is figurative sterile

Comment: …system produces ***unquestioning*** generations able to only regurgitate…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Poor educational system* is a singular countable noun and therefore needs a determiner -- in your case I think *a*. Also, the last part (able just to regurgitate) has a nonconventional word order. I would suggest the following:

"... such a poor educational system produces a scientifically sterile generation that is only able to regurgitate."

Answer (score 2):

> **Sterile** (adj.) not able to produce children or young

I believe "scientifically sterile generations" means that those *generations* are not able to produce science. That is not exactly the same as those *generations* having nothing to contribute to science. You can contribute to science, without producing science. Older generations can produce science, and the younger can contribute.

With that in mind, I would go with:

> **Unfit** (adj.) not of the necessary quality or standard to meet a particular purpose.

Which is implemented like this:

> ..such poor educational system produces scientifically <strike>sterile</strike>**unfit** generations, able just to regurgitate

Alternatively, you can look for a metaphor that relates to what you want to mean.

Example: a car with an empty tank (i.e. not able to produce) can still be refilled and get back to running (i.e. might have something to contribute). However, a broken car cannot run anyway. So these *generations* in your case, are like the broken car or a car without an engine.

> ..such poor educational system produces <strike>scientifically sterile generations</strike>**cars without engines,** able just to regurgitate

Example: Cristiano Ronaldo in the final match in Euro 2016 got injured (i.e. not able to produce) but he still was able to support the team. However, if CR7 had irreparably injured his feet (knock on wood 3x) he would not play football again (i.e. neither contribute nor produce). So, these *generations* in your case, are like a football athelete without feet, scientifically speaking.

> ..such poor educational system produces <strike>scientifically sterile generations</strike>**football atheletes without feet,** able just to regurgitate

Comment: What does produce science mean? What does contribute to science mean? …technology, agriculture, law, medicine, and other disciplines when substituted into the argument make little sense to me in your opening remark.

Comment: I like *barren* rather than sterile which has a slightly different implication.